# Android Show ProgressDialog onClick of AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, progressdialog, onclicklistener

I am trying to show a ProgressDialog in the onClick event of the AlertDialog, the code works but the ProgressDialog seems to be stuck behind the AlertDialog, which defeats the point

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Title").setMessage("Message").setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Title", "Text", true, false);
```

Comment: Why not dismiss the alert dialog?

Comment: Tried that, doesn't seem to work, because of the onClick event it seems to hold the AlertDialog at the front, if someone has a method of making this work better in ANY way, I would galdly look at it.

Comment: Got the issue, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Title").setMessage("Progress?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface alertDialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                alertDialog.dismiss();
                showProgressDlg();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
```

---

```
public void showProgressDlg()
    {
        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        //All pd properties...
    }
```

Comment: I have tried everything that has come to mind, this didn't work either, you would be willing to take a look at the code with me through teamviewer, I need some serious assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I got the issue this morning.

I tried to put it in a `this.runOnUiThread(...)` but not effect.
I tried with a copy of `this`/`MyActivity.this`, but nothin'.

The trick (I don't understand the reason) : make your `ProgressDialog` class attribute, don't define it from a method called from your AlertDialog `onClick`.

`private ProgressDialog pDialog;`

My situation was exactly yours, and now it works.
Maybe it will help someone.